# installing libX11.a, libX11.so and Xlib.h

Tags: system-installation

I installed libx11-dev with following command;

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
```

I need libX11.a, libX11.so and Xlib.h files. When I searched these files I couldn't locate them. I need to install libX11.a into /usr/lib/X11, libX11.so into /usr/lib/X11 and Xlib.h into /usr/include/X11.

How can I install these files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `apt-file search [filename]` to determine the package that provides these files, as well as their location.

libX11.a:

`libx11-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.a`

libX11.so:

`libx11-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so`

Xlib.h:

`libx11-dev: /usr/include/X11/Xlib.h`

So yes, you ought to have them already.